# Adding a HTML header and footer to plaintext emails sent from a legacy Order Management System

Tags: email, smtp

We're using a legacy Order Management System called Stone Edge Order Manager which allows us to send emails to customers with data populated from their account and order information.

It has a very basic templating system that allows us to edit the emails before they are sent to add additional information. Unfortunately the HTML support is very inflexible and does not allow us to edit messages when sent in HTML format. That means we can only send plain-text emails to customers.

We would like to be able to send professional looking emails to our customers and already have a HTML template we are using in other software.

There are two possible ways I can think of to achieve this goal.

A SMTP server that allows us to modify messages being sent via the SMTP server. Something that can prepend a header and append a footer into the message and change the mimetype.

An external email client software that can apply a HTML template to emails sent. The Order Manager software supports sending via the default email client setup on the workstation.

I've tried searching for more details on both possible solutions but I'm having trouble finding any relevant results. Surely I'm not the first administrator to want to do this?

Comment: How does the legacy system sends emails? Does it send via local sendmail program (hardcoded path/configurable path) or via configurable SMTP host/host&port? Which SMTP/MTA server do you use? (Postfix/Sendmail/Exim/... , MS Exchange/...)

Comment: The system runs on Windows 7 with an MSSQL backend server. It can be configured to either send emails via the default configured email client on the system (outlook, thunderbird) or via a configurable SMTP server. SMTP supports host, port, SSL. We're currently using our hosting provider's SMTP server so we don't have control over that. I have been considering running our own SMTP server so we can avoid the repuation hit we get from using those shared servers.

Comment: After some more research it appears that modifying messages at the SMTP server is bad idea: https://github.com/Exim/exim/wiki/Q1601